# Formal complex manifold without dd^c

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, rational-homotopy-theory

Is there an example of compact complex manifold, which is formal, but does not admit complex structure satisfying $dd^c$-lemma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Hopf surface $S^1 \times S^3$ is formal but does not admit a complex structure satisfying the $dd^c$ lemma. Indeed, a closed four-manifold admitting a complex structure satisfying the $dd^c$ lemma (equivalently the $\partial \bar \partial$ lemma) admits a Kähler structure and thus has even first Betti number.

Comment: (The most obvious things to look at usually fall out of your head.) Are there simply connected ones?

Comment: Such examples do not exist among 4-manifolds (since any simply connected four-manifold admitting a complex structure also admits a Kähler structure). Next, in dimension 6, it helps that any simply connected six-manifold is formal, but I do not know any examples that do not admit a complex structure satisfying the $dd^c$ lemma (nor do I know an example in still higher dimensions).